# how to solve input string was not in correct format while the textbox is the result of the calculation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

so I'm trying to do some calculation and textbox66 here should be the result, but it ended up showing "input string was not in correct format". how can I fixed this? thankyou

```cs
else if (2.8 < fsF & fsF <= 3)
{
    textBox66.Text = ((((0.8 * fF + 0.7) - (0.8 * fF + 0.67)) * (fsF - 2.8) / 0.2) +
        (0.8 * fF + 0.67)).ToString();
}

var w0 = Convert.ToDecimal(float.Parse(textBox66.Text));
var wdesain = Convert.ToDouble(w0 * F * web00 / 1000);`
```

Comment: I suppose the exception occurs on `float.Parse(textBox66.Text)`, right? What is the content of `textBox66.Text`? What is your current culture's decimal separator?

Comment: and also, what are the types of all these variables?

Comment: why do you use `&` instead of `&&`?

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to convert a string to a float, just convert it to a decimal afterwards.

```cs
decimal w0 = Decimal.Parse(textBox66.Text);
```

Also, the numbers like `0.8` are of type `double`. `0.8m` is decimal. `0.8f` is float. Of what type are the variables `fsF`, `fF`? Be more consistent with the numeric types. Intermixing all these type makes no sense.

We see only an `else if` setting the value of the textbox. What happens in the other cases? If the textbox is empty (`textBox66.Text == ""`), then the conversion will fail.